# Why was the marathon World Record not 2:03:02 in 2011?

Tags: running, records, marathon, road-running

Why exactly was Geoffrey Mutai's 2:03:02 in [Boston (2011)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2011_Boston_Marathon) not deemed the [marathon World Record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marathon_world_record_progression) at the time?

Comment: Just waiting for someone to run faster so the real answer can become, "Because so-and-so ran 2:03:01 in Berlin on $DATE."

Comment: :) and there it is.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The course for the Boston Marathon does not meet two of the criteria necessary for ratification of world or American records:

- "The start and finish points of a course, measured along a theoretical straight line between them, shall not be further apart than 50% of the race distance." [i.e., 13.1 miles (21.1 km) for the ~26.2 mile (~42.2 km) marathon distance]
- "The decrease in elevation between the start and finish shall not exceed an average of one in a thousand, i.e. 1m per km." [i.e., 42.2 m for the ~42.2 km marathon distance]

The Boston course has an endpoint about 24.3 miles (39 km) from the start point, and the endpoint is also 459 feet (139 m) lower than the start point.

source: [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boston_Marathon)

Comment: [IAAF COMPETITION RULES 2012-2013](http://www.iaaf.org/mm/Document/06/28/89/62889_PDF_English.pdf): rule 260.28 (approximate page 244).

Comment: The second point makes sense, but what is the reason for the first point?

Answer (score 34):

Due to the fact that the Boston course is a net downhill in excess of the limit allowed by the world record setting body.

His time is recognized as the fastest marathon ever...but not the world record.

Comment: The [IAAF Site](http://www.iaaf.org/LRR11/news/newsid=59806.html) has more details.

Answer (score 12):

Because Dennis Kimetto ran 2:02:57 in Berlin on September 28, 2014.

Comment: Just in case nobody gets the joke: the answer selected as accepted was correct at the time of asking. For 3+ years, Mutai's time was the fastest ever, but not the WR; now Kimetto's mark from Berlin is both (pending ratification).

Comment: ...and now that Eliud Kipchoge has run sub-2:02, even this answer is wrong. :)